# Why can't I set ActionController Relative URL Root in a JRuby on Rails app running on Jetty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jetty, jruby

I am developing a Ruby on Rails app but am running it with JRuby in Jetty under a context path of `/app`.

I'm using Rails 3.0.5, JRuby 1.6.0 and Jetty 6.1.22

When I deploy to Jetty, the relative URLs of the static resources is `/stylesheets/*` and `/javascripts/*`, not `/app/stylesheets/*` and `/app/javascripts/*` and is hence breaking styling and client-side functionality.

I tried adding `config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/app'` to `config/environments/production.rb` but Jetty cannot initialise the application.

The stack trace from Jetty looks like:

> 2011-03-23
>   16:19:54.062:WARN:/app:Error:
>   application initialization failed
>   org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException:
>   unable to create shared application
>   instance
>           at org.jruby.rack.SharedRackApplicationFactory.init(SharedRackApplicationFactory.java:39)
>           at org.jruby.rack.RackServletContextListener.contextInitialized(RackServletContextListener.java:44)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
>           at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
>           at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
>           at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
>           at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>           at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)
>           at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
>           at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:441)
>           at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)

How can I configure this setting and not have Jetty blow up when initialising the app?

Comment: Just adding `config.action_controller.relative_url_root` is preventing the application from initiailizing?

Answer (score 0):

`config.action_controller.relative_url_root` is removed in Rails 3. I have a post about this on my website: [Deploying a Rails 3.1 app to subdirectory in Apache](http://lassebunk.dk/2011/09/09/deploying-a-rails-3-1-app-to-subdirectory-in-apache/). Though it's written for Apache, you should be able to rewrite it to Jetty.